# In C++ whats the difference between setters and getters and constructors?

Tags: c++, oop

If we use constructors do we need to use setters and getters. I am totally confused between these terms could someone please elaborate.

Comment: They are completely orthogonal. Constructors are about initializing objects. getters and setters are about the API of that object.

Comment: "Setters" are often completely unnecessary and circumvent encapsulation. Use a constructor to build an object, and "Getters" to access properties. "Getters" tend to defeat polymorphism and are also often completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 7):

> If we use constructors do we need to use setters and getters

First of all you cannot have a class without a constructor, when you do not provide any compiler will generate them for you. You should not use setters and getters unrelated if you define your own constructor or not. When you design a class you design it's interface and then add member variables to implement that behavior and those members are internal representation of the class and outside world should not be aware of them - that is what data encapsulation is for and that's why we make them private or protected. When you add members first and then blindly provide getters and/or setters - that is a wrong approach to OOD.

Comment: let's say I have a class car
class car {
private: int year,cc; 

car (int Year, int CC) {
year = year;
cc=CC;
}
If I did this and didn't implement setter and getters there won't be any different if I did implement setters and getter. So, I am confused why go through the trouble of setters and getters when you can do that using a constructor.

Comment: @CyborgGamer again, you got it wrong - you started with class and it's data members, but you should start with a class and it's public interface. Then when interface is properly designed, to implement this interface you add members and then you may create a constructor if necessary to initialize them, not the other way around. Do not create data members first and then add setters and getters for them - that's an incorrect though pretty common way of doing OOD.

Answer (score 1):

Use constructors to create objects. Use getters to get information from an already existing object. Use setters to change an already existing object.

Any particular class may will need one or more of these things but not every class will need all of them. In particular *immutable* classes can't be modifed after they've been created so don't need setters.

Answer (score 1):

The two things are very different.

A **constructor** is a function that is called by the system whenever an object is created. If you don't define one yourself, the compiler will provide a default one. Whatever happens, a constructor will be called exactly once for each object you create. Its purpose is usually to set up valid values for all members of the class.

By contrast, **getters** and **setters** are just regular functions — methods whose purpose is to provide access to individual members of a class (read and write acces, respectively). There is no requirement to provide one, and they are not automatically generated; conversely, if one is provided, it may be called as often as you like.

Hopefully it's clear how a constructor differs from set/getters.

Comment: Also, you don't need to worry so much about multithreading with a constructor.